# Apk ler script externo e executa-lo

Tags: android, script

No C# é possível compilar em tempo de execução código externo escrito em C# mesmo e rodar ele dentro da aplicação, sem ter necessidade de utilizar alguma linguagem de Script.

Mas nunca utilizei nada assim com Java, mais especificamente para Android, então não sei bem ao certo pelo o que começar a procurar. Quais linguagem Scripts seriam mais fáceis de utilizar junto com Java/Android. Preciso dela apenas para ter como o usuário poder criar formulas matemáticas que possam interagir com os objetos, sem precisar criar uma nova versão do Apk toda vez que surgir uma necessidade nova.

Sei dos problemas que podem causar um interpretador de script integrado a aplicação, mas neste caso não é um problema, a Apk é de uso interno apenas então segurança ou até possíveis crashes não é problema.

Comment: Veja se isso lhe dá uma luz - http://stackoverflow.com/q/15218892/2891567

Comment: Acho que é mais ou menos isso, vou dar uma pesquisada mais a fundo.